# How to meditate after become sotapannna?

Tags: vipassana

If someone sees self is an illusion.it disappears with  dvesha.is that  the state lord buddha said, anatta ?how do you meditate thereafter?

Answer (score 2):

The Noble 8 Fold Path is the practice up to Sotapanna.

[image]

Source: [Maha Cattarīsaka Sutta](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/6.10-Maha-Cattarisaka-S-m117-piya.pdf) intorduction

To go beyond Sotapanna one must add 2 more elements under liberation/release which are:

- right knowledge
- right freedom

[image]

[Maha Cattarīsaka Sutta](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/6.10-Maha-Cattarisaka-S-m117-piya.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Well the patidapada of the sekha is at MN53
https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.053.than.html

plenty of suttas talk about the sekhas like
https://suttacentral.net/an5.90/en/sujato
https://suttacentral.net/search?query=sekha

sometimes a sekha is anyone who trains in the dhamma, not the usual non puthujjana who is yet to be reach nibanna.

For sotapanna, you can read
https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn55/sn55.040.than.html

> "And how, Nandiya, does a disciple of the noble ones live heedfully?
>   There is the case where a disciple of the noble ones is endowed with
>   verified confidence in the Awakened One... Not content with that
>   verified confidence in the Awakened One, he exerts himself further in
>   solitude by day or seclusion by night. For him, living thus heedfully,
>   joy arises. In one who has joy, rapture arises. In one who has
>   rapture, the body becomes serene. When the body is serene, one feels
>   pleasure. Feeling pleasure, the mind becomes centered. When the mind
>   is centered, phenomena become manifest. When phenomena are manifest,
>   he is reckoned as one who dwells heedfully.
>
> "Furthermore, the disciple of the noble ones is endowed with verified
>   confidence in the Dhamma... verified confidence in the Sangha...
>   virtues that are appealing to the noble ones: untorn, unbroken,
>   unspotted, unsplattered, liberating, praised by the wise, untarnished,
>   leading to concentration. Not content with those virtues pleasing to
>   the noble ones, he exerts himself further in solitude by day or
>   seclusion by night. For him, living thus heedfully, joy arises. In one
>   who has joy, rapture arises. In one who has rapture, the body becomes
>   serene. When the body is serene, one feels pleasure. Feeling pleasure,
>   the mind becomes centered. When the mind is centered, phenomena become
>   manifest. When phenomena are manifest, he is reckoned as one who
>   dwells heedfully.